# Swift - create an array of mixed values

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to create an array that looks like this using Swift:

[("2018 Q4",63150), ("2019 Q1",50900), ("2019 Q2",77550), ("2019 Q3",79600), ("2019 Q4",92550)]

Thank you

I tried creating a stuct:

```
struct dataPoint {
    var dateTime: String = ""
    var value: Int = 0
}
```

And then when I try to populate the array, I end up with this:

```
[ dataPoint(dateTime: "2018 Q4", value: 63150), dataPoint(dateTime: "2019 Q1", value: 50900), dataPoint(dateTime: "2019 Q2", value: 77550), dataPoint(dateTime: "2019 Q3", value: 79600), dataPoint(dateTime: "2019 Q4", value: 92550) ]
```

I would like the array to look like this:

```
[("2018 Q4",63150), ("2019 Q1",50900), ("2019 Q2",77550), ("2019 Q3",79600), ("2019 Q4",92550)]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and describe what you have already tried using an [example].

Comment: What is the purpose of the array, your solution with a struct looks much better than your expected result in my opinion. Why is it important what the array looks like?

Comment: I am trying to use SwiftUICharts (https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView). To use the BarChartView, I need to structure the input data in the format described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
func getData() {

    var arr = [(String, Int)]()

    for item in session.practiceRecordList {
        if item.practiceType == self.practiceSelection {
            if item.handType == "Forehand" {
                let a = DateFormatMMDDYY(dateString: item.timeStamp)
                let b = Int(item.practiceCount!/item.duration!)
                arr.append((a,b))
            } else {
                let a = DateFormatMMDDYY(dateString: item.timeStamp)
                let b = Int(item.practiceCount!/item.duration!)
                arr.append((a,b))
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    print(arr)

}
```